# build command for expo react native

Tags: react-native, docker, build, expo, eas

I'm trying to host a React Native Expo app on AWS using Docker, and to build it I run the command `eas build -p ios`. This doesn't work though, because Docker doesn't recognize eas until it is installed, and after installation, it requires an account. I don't want to have an actual account tied to my application, because I'd need to hardcode the username and password into the Dockerfile, so how can I get around this?